# prepend the "\\?\" string to the path - DriverPackageUninstall

Tags: c, winapi, unicode, wdk

I used `DriverPackageUninstall`, to uninstall my driver. For this API I need to give "Inf Path" as the input. And I need to give this path as UNICODE string. To do this, I took the following statement from MSDN as reference.

> For a Unicode string, the maximum length is 32,767 characters. If you
>   use the Unicode version, prepend the "\?\" string to the path. For
>   general information about the format of file path strings, see  Naming
>   a File in the MSDN Library.

But when I  try the same in my code its not working. Can someone give me some examples on how to prepend the "\?\" before the path? Thanks..

UPDATE :

I tried with the below code as sample

```
#define UNICODE
#define _UNIOCDE
#define WINVER 0x501

    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <tchar.h>

    int main () {
        PTCHAR DriverPackageInfPath = TEXT("\\?\\c:\\Documents and Settings\\Desktop\\My.inf");

        FILE * Log;
         Log = _wfopen( TEXT(DriverPackageInfPath, TEXT("a"));

         if ( Log == NULL ) {
           MessageBox(NULL, TEXT ( "Unable to open INF file\n" ),
               TEXT ( "Installation Error" ), 0 | MB_ICONSTOP );
           exit ( 1 );
         } else {
                printf ("INF file opened successfully\n");
         }

         return 0;
    }
```

UPDATE:

".\dist\Driver\My.inf" How to add "\\?\" before this kind of paths? "\\?\.\dist\Driver\My.inf" is not working.

Comment: Is the string you have already in Unicode?

Answer (score 5):

You have error in string constant:

```
TEXT("\\?\\c:\\Documents ...."
```

should be

```
TEXT("\\\\?\\c:\\Documents  ...."
```

Read carefully, escape carefully : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff552316%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

**UPDATE:**

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247.aspx :

**Win32 File Namespaces**

The Win32 namespace prefixing and conventions are summarized in this section and the following section, with descriptions of how they are used. Note that these examples are intended for use with the Windows API functions and do not all necessarily work with Windows shell applications such as Windows Explorer. For this reason there is a wider range of possible paths than is usually available from Windows shell applications, and Windows applications that take advantage of this can be developed using these namespace conventions.

For file I/O, the "\?\" prefix to a path string tells the Windows APIs to disable all string parsing and to send the string that follows it straight to the file system. For example, if the file system supports large paths and file names, you can exceed the MAX_PATH limits that are otherwise enforced by the Windows APIs. For more information about the normal maximum path limitation, see the previous section Maximum Path Length Limitation.

Because it turns off automatic expansion of the path string, the "\?\" prefix **also allows the use of ".." and "." in the path names**, which can be useful if you are attempting to perform operations on a file with these otherwise reserved relative path specifiers as part of the fully qualified path.

**Win32 Device Namespaces**

The "\.\" prefix will access the Win32 device namespace instead of the Win32 file namespace. This is how access to physical disks and volumes is accomplished directly, without going through the file system, if the API supports this type of access. You can access many devices other than disks this way (using the CreateFile and DefineDosDevice functions, for example).

For example, if you want to open the system's serial communications port 1, you can use "COM1" in the call to the CreateFile function. This works because COM1–COM9 are part of the reserved names in the NT namespace, although using the "\.\" prefix will also work with these device names. By comparison, if you have a 100 port serial expansion board installed and want to open COM56, you cannot open it using "COM56" because there is no predefined NT namespace for COM56. You will need to open it using "\.\COM56" because "\.\" goes directly to the device namespace without attempting to locate a predefined alias.

Another example of using the Win32 device namespace is using the CreateFile function with "\.\PhysicalDiskX" (where X is a valid integer value) or "\.\CdRomX". This allows you to access those devices directly, bypassing the file system. This works because these device names are created by the system as these devices are enumerated, and some drivers will also create other aliases in the system. For example, the device driver that implements the name "C:\" has its own namespace that also happens to be the file system.

APIs that go through the CreateFile function generally work with the "\.\" prefix because CreateFile is the function used to open both files and devices, depending on the parameters you use.

**If you're working with Windows API functions, you should use the "\.\" prefix to access devices only and not files.**

Most APIs won't support "\.\"; only those that are designed to work with the device namespace will recognize it. Always check the reference topic for each API to be sure.

So your relative path can be

```
\\?\.\dist\driver\My.inf
```

escaped form is

```
\\\\?\\.\\dist\\driver\\My.inf
```

Comment: ".\\dist\\Driver\\My.inf" How to add "\\\\?\\" before this kind of paths? "\\\\?\\.\\dist\\Driver\\My.inf" is not working.

Comment: I gave \\?\.\dist\driver\My.inf as path and getting the following errors.[Warning] unknown escape sequence: '\.' [enabled by default] 
[Warning] unknown escape sequence: '\d' [enabled by default] 
[Warning] unknown escape sequence: '\D' [enabled by default]

Comment: @user1317084 again and again, use escaped form \\\\?\\.\\dist\\driver\\My.inf EVERYITIME use escaped string in C/C++

Comment: sorry to trouble you by silly questions. \\\\?\\.\\dist\\driver\\My.inf, I used this earlier and the path is not getting recognised. This is in my first comment. if I give the full path the path gets recognised. "\\\\?\\c:\\dist\\driver\\My.inf".

Answer (score 2):

You only need to prepend `\\?\` to the path if it is longer than `MAX_PATH` characters.

Comment: So do I need to check whether my path is MAX_PATH or not?

Comment: @user1317084 It wasn't clear to me whether you were actually working with long paths or not.

Comment: ".\\dist\\Driver\\My.inf" How to add "\\\\?\\" before this kind of paths? "\\\\?\\.\\dist\\Driver\\My.inf" is not working.

Comment: Thanks Neil and can you/anyone give some reference link. Can some one else confirm what Neil said ?

Comment: A path is absolute if it begins with a backslash, optionally preceded by a drive letter. All UNC names with two backslashes are also absolute paths. See MSDN (search for **Fully Qualified vs. Relative Paths**).